# Custom Routing with singular resource error

Tags: ruby-on-rails, routes

my routes are looking like this

routes.rb

```
 get    '/:pimp_id/mepagers(.:format)',     :to => 'mepagers#index',    :as => 'mepagers'
 get    '/:pimp_id/mepager/new(.:format)',  :to => 'mepagers#new',      :as => 'new_mepager'
 get    '/:pimp_id/mepager/edit(.:format)', :to => 'mepagers#edit',     :as => 'edit_mepager'
 get    '/:pimp_id/mepager(.:format)',      :to => 'mepagers#show',     :as => 'mepager'
 post   '/:pimp_id/mepager(.:format)',      :to => 'mepagers#create',   :as => 'create_mepager'
 put    '/:pimp_id/mepager(.:format)',      :to => 'mepagers#update'
 patch  '/:pimp_id/mepager(.:format)',      :to => 'mepagers#update'
 delete '/:pimp_id/mepager(.:format)',      :to => 'mepagers#destroy'
```

I tried to take the form from

```
HTTP Verb Path Controller#Action Used for 
GET /geocoder/new geocoders#new return an HTML form for creating the geocoder 
POST /geocoder geocoders#create create the new geocoder 
GET /geocoder geocoders#show display the one and only geocoder resource 
GET /geocoder/edit geocoders#edit return an HTML form for editing the geocoder 
PATCH/PUT /geocoder geocoders#update update the one and only geocoder resource 
DELETE /geocoder geocoders#destroy delete the geocoder resource
```

(source http://guides.rubyonrails.org/routing.html)

But when I click the submit button on /1/mepager/new I get following error:

```
Routing Error
No route matches [POST] "/1/mepager/new"
```

I even tried to change the post actions route to /1/mepager/new but that didnt help at all because he cant find the param for mepager then. Coudlnt find anything similar on google so I hope someone can help this routing makes me sick!

new.html.erb

```
<%= render 'form' %>

<%= link_to 'Back', pimps_path %>
```

_form.html.erb

```
<%= form_for 'mepager_path' do |f| %>

  <% if @mepager.errors.any? %>
    <div id="error_explanation">
      <h2><%= pluralize(@mepager.errors.count, "error") %> prohibited this mepager from being saved:</h2>

      <ul>
      <% @mepager.errors.full_messages.each do |msg| %>
        <li><%= msg %></li>
      <% end %>
      </ul>
    </div>
  <% end %>


<table style="border:1px solid black; border-spacing:5px"; width="1521" bgcolor="#DFDFDF">

    <colgroup>
        <col width="1050">
        <col width="300">
    </colgroup>

    <tr> <td>   <h1>NEW: ID# Title  </td>   <td> <h1>Programme:  a350</h1></td> </tr>
</table>





<p id="notice"><%= notice %>

<table style="border:1px solid black; border-spacing:5px"; width="1500"; height="640">

    <tr>
        <th rowspan="3">
            <table style="border:1px solid black; border-spacing:5px"; width="1150"; height="506">
                <colgroup>
                    <col width="675">
                    <col width="675">
                </colgroup>


                <tr>    <th colspan="2" align="left" height="10">   <u><strong>Change description & pictures:</strong></u>  </th>   </tr>

                <tr>    <th colspan="2" align="left" height="10">   <u><b>Pre:</b></u>                                      </th>   </tr>                   
                <tr>    
                    <td align="left" valign="top">  <div class="field"> <%= f.text_area :pre, :size=>"100x12"%> </div>  </td>   
                    <td>    
                        <div class="actions">     
                            <%= file_field_tag :file %>   
                            <%= submit_tag "Upload image" %> 
                        </div> 
                    </td>       
                </tr>

                <tr>    <th colspan="2" align="left" height="10">   <u><b>Post:</b></u>                                     </th>   </tr>
                <tr>    
                    <td align="left" valign="top">  <div class="field"> <%= f.text_area :post, :size=>"100x12" %>   </div>  </td>   
                    <td>
                        <div class="actions">     
                            <%= file_field_tag :file %>   
                            <%= submit_tag "Upload image" %> 
                        </div> 
                    </td>   
                </tr>




            </table>
        </th>
        <td valign="top">
            <table style="border:1px solid black; border-spacing:5px"; width="350"; height=135>
                <colgroup>
                    <col width="160">
                    <col width="190">
                </colgroup>

                <tr>    <th colspan="2" align="left" height="10">   <u><strong>Expected savings / overspend reduction:</strong></u> </th>                               </tr>       
                <tr>    <td align="left">   h/AC:   </td>   <td align="left">   <div class="field"> <%= f.number_field :save_h, :size=>5 %> </div>  </td>           </tr>
                <tr>    <td align="left">   concessions/AC: </td>   <td align="left">   <div class="field"> <%= f.number_field :save_c, :size=>5 %> </div>  </td>   </tr>
                <tr>    <td align="left">   others: </td>   <td align="left">   <div class="field"> <%= f.text_field :save_other, :size=>30 %>  </div>  </td>           </tr>           
            </table>
        </td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>
            <table style="border:1px solid black; border-spacing:5px"; width="350"; height=180>
                <colgroup>
                    <col width="160">
                    <col width="190">
                </colgroup>


                <tr>    <th colspan="2" align="left" height="10">   <u><strong>Affected domains / responsibility:</strong></u>  </th>                                       </tr>       
                <tr>    <td align="left">   Design: </td>   <td align="left">   <div class="field"> <%= f.text_field :affect_design, :size=>30 %>   </div>  </td>       </tr>
                <tr>    <td align="left">   Stress: </td>   <td align="left">   <div class="field"> <%= f.text_field :affect_stress, :size=>30 %>   </div>  </td>       </tr>
                <tr>    <td align="left">   Manufacturing:  </td>   <td align="left">   <div class="field"> <%= f.text_field :affect_me, :size=>30 %>   </div>  </td>   </tr>
                <tr>    <td align="left">   Others: </td>   <td align="left">   <div class="field"> <%= f.text_field :affect_other, :size=>30 %>    </div>  </td>       </tr>   
            </table>
        </td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>
            <table style="border:1px solid black; border-spacing:5px"; width="350"; height=135>
                <colgroup>
                    <col width="160">
                    <col width="190">
                </colgroup>

                <tr>    <th colspan="2" align="left" height="10">   <u><strong>Affected documents:</strong> </u>    </th>   </tr>       
                <tr>    <td align="left">   Drawing number/HTZ: </td>   <td align="left">   <div class="field"> <%= f.text_field :affect_dno, :size=>30 %>  </div>  </td>   </tr>
                <tr>    <td align="left">   Material ID:    </td>   <td align="left">   <div class="field"> <%= f.text_field :affect_mid, :size=>30 %>  </div>  </td>       </tr>
                <tr>    <td align="left">   Others: </td>   <td align="left">   <div class="field"> <%= f.text_field :affect_otherdoc, :size=>30 %> </div>  </td>               </tr>
            </table>            
        </td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>
            <table style="border:1px solid black; border-spacing:5px"; width="1150"; height=196>
                <tr height="10">    <th align="left">   <u><b>Comments / current status / further notes:</b></u>    </th>   </tr>       
                <tr>    <td align="left" valign="top">  <div class="field">  <%= f.text_area :save_h, :size=>"100x8"%> </div> </td>     </tr>       
            </table>
        </td>
        <td> 
            <table style="border:1px solid black; border-spacing:5px"; width="350"; height=150>
                <colgroup>
                    <col width="160">
                    <col width="190">
                </colgroup>

                <tr>    <th colspan="2" align="left" height="10">   <u><strong>General information:</strong></u>    </th>   </tr>   
                <tr>    <td align="left">   Idea owner: </td>   <td align="left">   <div class="field"> <%= f.text_field :owner, :size=>30 %>   </div>  </td>               </tr>
                <tr>    <td align="left">   Date of submission: </td>   <td align="left">   autofilled  </td>               </tr>
                <tr>    <td align="left">   PPS available:  </td>   <td align="left">   <div class="field"> <%= f.text_field :pps, :size=>30 %> </div>  </td>               </tr>
                <tr>    <td align="left">   Reference (VV/ZTV): </td>   <td align="left">   <div class="field"> <%= f.text_field :reference, :size=>30 %>   </div>  </td>   </tr>
            </table>
        </td>
    </tr>
</table>        



  <div class="actions">
    <%= f.submit "Create One Pager" %>
  </div>

<% end %>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

See documentation on `form_for` [here](http://apidock.com/rails/ActionView/Helpers/FormHelper/form_for)

Referring to the documentation linked to above; the `form_for` method takes a few parameters:

1. record
2. options
3. block

In your case, I think what you trying to do is pass the `'mepager_path'` named path as the URL to which the form should be submitted. However, you're missing separators for your `form_for` parameters so Rails thinks `'mepager_path'` is the value of the `record` parameter.

the `record` parameter is meant to convey information about the object which the form should describe so that Rails can infer properties of the object to make the form for you with minimal overhead to you, the developer. In your case, I think you can try someting like

```
<%= form_for :mepager, url: mepager_path do |f| %>
```

I'm also a Rails noob so I can't promise you my code samples are correct but the gist of my answer is that your `form_for` parameters are incorrect. As someone new to Rails, I'm constantly frustrated by different forms parameters can take. For me the multitude of forms make them difficult to read and I constantly have to make sure I'm not misinterpreting code. Also, hash syntax always confuses me.

My answer was taken from [here](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/getting_started.html#the-first-form). I've found it to be a very useful reference site.

Hope my answer helps you.

Comment: As far as I know the get request is only to get the formsheet for creating a new object. The submit button should trigger the post request then `post   '/:pimp_id/mepager(.:format)',      :to => 'mepagers#create'` but thats not happening somehow. Is it possible to change the submit function somewhere?

Comment: Can you add the view containing the form you are trying to submit?

Comment: Added the view and the rendered form!

Comment: Thanks for your effort. Unfortunately that didnt solved it. My normal form_for line was `<%= form_for mepager_path(@pimp) do |f| %>`. This should normally be correct if im not totally wrong.

Comment: hmm, [this](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/getting_started.html#the-first-form) sounds similar to what you are experiencing and I think my suggested answer was similar too. What happened when you tried `<%= form_for :mepager, {:url => 'mepager_path'} do |f| %>`?

Comment: Thanks I altered the line a bit and now it works, but you were totally right! Appreciate it alot my friend. Used this line in the end `<%= form_for :mepager, url: mepager_path do |f| %>`. If you take that into your answer above I will be happy to rate it!